# How can one create a hyperlink to link to the folder my file is saved in?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I was looking to create a hyperlink within excel that would open the folder where my current file is saved. I don't know where to begin, I found the question linked at the bottom and thought that would be a good start but I don't know how to trim the file name.

Linking to the saved files is easy enough when I working in a project (I use this template similar to One Note but with the excel calculation capabilities) but when I want to use my template for a new project I'd like the links to my source folders to transfer. I may not be explaining myself well.

If this is my current file:
**c:\desktop\homework\History\ClassCalendar.xlxs**
I would like the hyperlink to open the folder **c:\desktop\homework\History**, but if I changed where I save my document I'd like the hyperlink to change location too.

[How do you insert the current file name in Excel?](https://superuser.com/questions/606048/how-do-you-insert-the-current-file-name-in-excel)

Comment: Can you generate the file name (using the question you linked to), **append `\..`**, and pass that to a `HYPERLINK` function?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to reference a local file in most windows apps using the file:// protocol. However, I do not believe this works with opening folders.

Also, having the link in Excel update automatically when you move the file is just not possible.

Comment: You're trying too hard to answer something that isn't a question... and wouldn't be a useful question in the first place.  Cut your losses.

Comment: Killermist is a useless individual who can't answer a question if they themselves wont have a use for it.